# Short exact sequence of $\mathbb{R}[X]$-modules that does not split

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

What is an example of a short exact sequence of $\mathbb{R}[X]$-modules that does not split?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't understand the downvote, either someone can think of an example or not. There isnt very much to 'try'. I know the definitions of all the terms used, I just can't think of an example.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of exact sequences to try! Do you know the "splitting lemma", that characterizes exactly when a SES splits?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes I do, how does that help?

Comment: You can try finding an exact sequence such that the monomorphism admits no section, or the epimorphism admits no retraction. You can also try obtaining an exact sequence with the middle term indecomposable. Jordan forms should help. Remember an $\Bbb R[X]$-module is an $\Bbb R$-vector space with an endomorphism.

Comment: @Bob1993 If $R$ is an integral domain and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, $I\ne\{0\}$ and $I\ne R$, then $I$ is not a direct summand. Why? If it were a summand, it would be generated by an idempotent. What are the idempotents of $R$?

Comment: @egreg: It would seem that your $R = \mathbb{R}[X]$, univariate real polynomials?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, that's a particular case.

Comment: @egreg would $\mathbb{R}[X]/X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[X]/X^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[X]/X$ work?

Comment: @Bob1993 Just $0\to X\mathbb{R}[X]\to\mathbb{R}[X]\to \mathbb{R}[X]/X\mathbb{R}[X]\to 0$.

Comment: @egreg I don't fully understand that notation

Comment: @Bob1993 $X\mathbb{R}[X]$ is the ideal generated by $X$.

Comment: @Bob1993 your example works as well. It's just not following egreg's hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the basic relevant facts to get you thinking about the possibilities:

A short exact sequence $$0 \to A \overset{f}{\to} M \overset{g}{\to} B \to 0$$ is the data of a submodule $f(A) \subset M$, where $f$ encodes $A \simeq f(A)$, and its quotient $M/f(A) \simeq B$ via the quotient map $g$. The sequence is said to split if $M$ has a complementary submodule to $f(A)$ isomorphic to $B$, which will make the sequence isomorphic to the most basic possible example of a short exact sequence, $$0 \to A \overset{i}{\to} A \oplus B \overset{\pi}{\to} B \to 0,$$ where $i$ is inclusion into the first coordinate in $A \oplus B$ and $\pi$ is projection onto the second coordinate of $A \oplus B$.

An $\mathbb R[X]$-module is the same thing as the data of an $\mathbb R$-vector space $V$ together with a linear transformation $X: V \to V$ encoded by multiplication by $X$. A submodule corresponds to an invariant subspace of this linear transformation. So what you need is a linear transformation together with an invariant subspace with no complementary invariant subspace. This is a basic linear algebra problem.